# javascript/json how to remove an object from nested json array which got generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Im facing a small issue to remove an object from nested json array which will get generated dynamically. Below is the json..

Actually my requirement is like, I have a JSON Tree, and user can add or delete multiple nodes..

```
[{
"mainTxt": "test",
"subTxt": "SubTxt1",
"nodes": [{
    "mainTxt": "test",
    "subTxt": "SubTxt2",
    "nodes": [{
        "mainTxt": "test",
        "subTxt": "test Operations",
        "nodes": [{
            "mainTxt": "test",
            "subTxt": "test Operations",
            "nodes": [{
                "mainTxt": "test",
                "subTxt": "test Operations"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "mainTxt": "test",
    "subTxt": "SubTxt3",
    "nodes": [{
        "mainTxt": "test",
        "subTxt": "test Operations",
        "nodes": [{
            "mainTxt": "test",
            "subTxt": "test Operations"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "mainTxt": "test",
    "subTxt": "india"
}, {
    "mainTxt": "test",
    "subTxt": "SubTxt4"
}, {
    "mainTxt": "test",
    "subTxt": "SubTxt5"
}]
```

}]

Here the below code blocks may get added or removed dynamically

```
    "nodes": [{
                "mainTxt": "test",
                "subTxt": "test Operations"
            }]
and
{
        "mainTxt": "test",
        "subTxt": "SubTxt5"
    }
```

How can i remove above blocks which got added dynamically and after removing again i need to form the same JSON array.

I tried multiple ways in writing a loop by finding index of that particular object in array and tried to remove using splice() and delete() method. But it didn't worked properly.

Actually i dont want to delete the object based on value, I want to delete based on index(It may change if we are add or delete). Most of the solutions are provided based on the value.
Can someone please help me if there is any simple fix?

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can remove JSON attributes using (to delete `deeperattribute`):

```
delete myjson.attribute.deeperattribute
```

And you can add JSON attributes by just assigning them:

```
myjson.thirteen = 12;
```

*I'm not sure if I understood your problem, but I hope this would atleast help you on your way.*

Comment: Im not sure..how it will help. I just want to delete the object in that particular JSON.

Comment: @user2644620 `delete thatParticularJSON.object`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue with below code..

```
 removeTile:function(oEvt){
        this._deleteRecord(globalArray, selObject);
        _oModel.setData(oModelData);
},
    _deleteRecord:function(items, record){
if(items !== undefined){
for(var i=0;i< items.length;i++){
if(items[i]=== record){
                    items.splice(i,1);break;
}else{

                    this._deleteRecord(items[i].nodes, record);
}
}
}
}
```